# IonCube not loaded with PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, raspberry-pi, ioncube

I am following the instructions here to install the Filerun app on my Nginx server, running on Ubuntu / Raspberry Pi 4.

I downloaded the aarch64 version of IonCube and created a file `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/00-ioncube.ini` with contents

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_7.4.so
```

I verified that the referenced `so` file exists.

I then ran `sudo systemctl restart php7.4-fpm` and it shows that the service is running.

But when I do `php -v` I don't see IonCube mentioned:

```
$ php --version

PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Nov  8 2022 11:40:37) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

And when I visit the actual site I get an error saying:

> Site error: the ionCube PHP Loader needs to be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong version of IonCube. You can run  `php -i | head -5` to see the architecture:

```
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.4.33

System => Linux raspberrypi 5.15.76-v7l+ #1597 SMP Fri Nov 4 12:14:58 GMT 2022 armv7l
Build Date => Nov  8 2022 11:40:3
```

In my case it's `armv7l` (I was wrong to think it was aarch64).

Downloading the correct version from here solved the problem https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php